# creating pdf on server gives error : Unable to connect to the remote server

Tags: .net, https, itext

I have code for creating pdf dynamically. I had used **iTextSharp, VS 2010, .Net 4.0**
Every thing was going fine and working good on my local.

When I have uploaded on Secure Server (https) it gives error like :

```
Unable to connect to the remote server
```

It is working fine on server localhost when I was debugging. Error only occur when calling remotely from any other PC (from URL).

what may causes problem ??

**Update** :

I have checked all code again.. and find one thing..

I had put a image which source is like :

```
<img src='https://siteurl.com/pdf/11111111.png' alt='' />
```

that gives problem : currently I have put static relative path but why it gives error ???
because in future I have to use same in many places

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring iTextSharp for a moment, try this following code on your production server, obviously replacing the URL with your problem URL.

```
using(var w = new System.Net.WebClient()){
    w.DownloadData(@"https://siteurl.com/pdf/11111111.png");
}
```

If this gives you an exception then your server is having a problem talking to the host specified. Sometimes, NAT/Firewall rules have problems using external resolution for internal resources. You might need to update local DNS or add an entry to a local hosts file to resolve this.

If the above doesn't give you an exception let us know and we can troubleshoot further.